# problem with dynamic loading content with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loading, dynamic

I'm working on a website that is dynamically loading content in a DIV.
Everything works fine except when the content contains a jquery plugin (f.e. a twitterfeed) the jquery plugin doesn't work..anybody knows how to get the plugins to work?

```
$(function() {

    var newHash      = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
        baseHeight   = 0,
        $el;


    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash) {
            $mainContent
                .find("#guts")
                .fadeOut(200, function() {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                        $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                            $pageWrap.animate({
                                height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                            });
                        });
                        $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                        $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                    });
                });


        };

    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');


});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use $.load with a selector ($(target).load("url **#selector**")), jQuery removes all SCRIPT tags from response.

Some solutions that come to my mind are:

1. changing the back-end to return only the content required by the script
2. do a $.get request, treat the reponse as plain text, do string manipulation to extract only the parts you need and then convert the result to DOM nodes. To do it *right*, a HTML parser is needed.

Comment: Actually, it *always* removes the `<script>` tags, but the difference is that when you ".load()" with a selector it doesn't execute the scripts. [The bug.](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6307)

Comment: +1 - didn't know this. I take it the solution would be to split them at source (into `<scr ipt>` maybe), and then get jQuery to regex them back together once it's been loaded?

Comment: I'd suggest your backend should return only the content required by your script, so jQuery wouldn't have to search for #guts.

Comment: how you mean change the back-end?

Comment: The script is doing a HTTP request, so you can have a script on the server side that will just reply with contents of <div id="guts"> and not with the whole page content. Just send some additional params (eg. using the URL) that will tell the server-side script that you want to have only part of the content.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I wanted to mention that I'm having a similar problem.  I've noticed, however, that when my content is loaded via $.load(), any javascript/jquery within that content will still trigger if I use setTimeout to delay it about a second.  This tells me that jQuery is not actually removing the script tags and does run the script at some point.  Unfortunately, using setTimeout alone is a bit unreliable, but it's something.

Comment: Well, actually now setTimeout doesn't seem to be working any more.  Not sure what changed.